# Laravel mix removes subfolder from image path

Tags: laravel-mix

I've set up an alias for my `public` folder where I've placed my images.

So they are inside `public/images`. I have a subfolder for certain types of images - in this case, card brands.

They're in `public/images/card-brands`

Here is my alias config:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
   resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
      alias: {
         '@': __dirname + '/resources/js',
         '@public' : __dirname +  '/public'
      },
   },
})
```

I'm importing the images in my vue component file:

```
import amex from '@public/images/card-brands/amex.svg'
import discover from '@public/images/card-brands/discover.svg'
import visa from '@public/images/card-brands/visa.svg'
import mastercard from '@public/images/card-brands/mastercard.svg'
```

Then using it inside my components data like so:

```
export default {

  name: 'PaymentMethod',
  data() {
      return {
       ...
        visaSvg: visa,
        mastercardSvg: mastercard,
        discoverSvg: discover,
        amexSvg: amex,
        currentCardBrand: this.initialCurrentCardBrand
       ...
      }
  },
props: {
...
initialCurrentCardBrand: String,
...
}
computed: {
 getCurrentCardBrandSvg() {
        switch (this.currentCardBrand) {
            case 'mastercard':
                return this.mastercardSvg;
            break;
            case 'visa':
                return this.visaSvg;
            break;
            case 'amex':
                return this.amexSvg;
            break;
            case 'discover':
                return this.discoverSvg;
            break;
        }
    }
}
...
```

Finally, I'm using it on my template as and image src: `<img class="w-10" :src="getCurrentCardBrandSvg">`

Now, even though the images and my import path are using the `card-brands` subfolder, the URL that is generated ignores this and just looks for the images in the root `images` folder.

It should be:

`/public/images/card-brands/visa.svg`
but it's generating as
`/public/images/visa.svg`

How can I get it to keep my subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead `{{ asset('/images/card-brands/mastercard.svg')) }}`
I faced a similar issue in laravel. I used the above format.Please correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: I was able to figure out my issue. I think your answer relates to Laravel Blade templates? I'm importing via javascript files

Comment: how did you solve it...what was the issue actually?

Comment: i posted an answer. if i have my images in `/resources/images` instead of `/public/images`, the JS will load the correct path and output it into public automatically. however, to grab images via blade templates, i'd need them in the public folder. so it's a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This could be slightly wrong. It works correctly for importing images via javascript, but I think grabbing images via laravel in blade templates still needs the images in the public folder.

The issue was not knowing that I was supposed to put my images folder inside the resources folder rather than public.

Laravel Mix will compile the images like it does the JS and SCSS and place it in public automatically.

So I created an images folder in resources, deleted my manually made images folder in public, and made an alias:

```
 alias: {
         '@images':  __dirname + '/resources/images'
    }
```

and now I can link to that inside my vue component.

```
import amex from '@images/card-brands/amex.svg'
import discover from '@images/card-brands/discover.svg'
import visa from '@images/card-brands/visa.svg'
import mastercard from '@images/card-brands/mastercard.svg'
```

The generated images will automatically be placed in public on the root level once I run `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`